# Select Column copy another

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I got this:

```
+--------+------+
| id  | name    |
+--------+------+
| 1   | George  |  
| 2   | Mathew  |  
| 3   | Michael | 
| 4   | Jones   |
+--------+------+
```

Now what I want to do is this.

I want to find my name Michael and copy the id "3" of Michael into a string variable in VS10

Comment: Use an entity framework like [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594)

Comment: SELECT id WHERE name="Michael" ... ?

Comment: You might start by going back and talking with your teacher...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following query to select the `id` column from the table and specifying the name condition in the `WHERE` clause

```
Select id from table where name = 'Michael'
```

If you are using Csharp in visual studio 2010, you can do something like this:

```
string idValue = String.Empty
string query = " Select id from table where name = 'Michael'";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
SqlDataReader reader;
connection.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
While(reader.Read())
{
idValue = reader["id"].ToString();
}
connection.Close();
return idValue;
```

In the above code, `idValue` is the `id` of the name you searching for and `connectionString`is a connection string to your database.

You can also use lambda like this:

```
string idVal = Table.Where(a => a.name== "Michael")
               .Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to establish connection between yout application and database using  mysql .net connector.
[This](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html) article should help you with that.

Then you should query the database from within your application.
Appropriate SQL query for your request will be `"SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'Michael'"`